# How to detect UI-Interactions in VS-Code using the extension API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to detect (listen to) UI-interactions that the user performs in VS-Code? Like for example clicking the "run" button directly in the editor window or selecting an action from the action bar above (e.g. File > save)?
I looked through the extension API but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm also searching a solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same.
As far as I read this is not possible, due to concerns about performance and some other issues.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78091#issuecomment-518545491 for the comments.